Android custom image with diagonal

I want to create a layout like this. It has 2 images with a diagonal running across the 2 images.
Below is my xml layout.
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginVertical="@dimen/margin_100">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/frame_first_image"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:background="@drawable/frame_border_selector"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/frame_second_image"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <io.github.florent37.shapeofview.shapes.DiagonalView
            android:id="@+id/diagonalView_top"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginHorizontal="@dimen/margin_10"
            android:background="@color/white"
            app:shape_diagonal_angle="1"
            app:shape_diagonal_position="bottom">

            <com.jsibbold.zoomage.ZoomageView
                android:id="@+id/img_first_image"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginHorizontal="@dimen/margin_2"
                android:layout_marginVertical="@dimen/margin_2"
                android:contentDescription="@null"
                android:scaleType="matrix"
                android:src="@color/black"
                app:zoomage_animateOnReset="true"
                app:zoomage_autoCenter="true"
                app:zoomage_autoResetMode="UNDER"
                app:zoomage_maxScale="8"
                app:zoomage_minScale="0.6"
                app:zoomage_restrictBounds="false"
                app:zoomage_translatable="true"
                app:zoomage_zoomable="true" />
        </io.github.florent37.shapeofview.shapes.DiagonalView>

    </FrameLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/frame_second_image"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:background="@drawable/frame_border_selector"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/frame_first_image">

        <io.github.florent37.shapeofview.shapes.DiagonalView
            android:id="@+id/diagonalView_bottom"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginHorizontal="@dimen/margin_10"
            android:background="@color/white"
            app:shape_diagonal_angle="-1"
            app:shape_diagonal_position="top">

            <com.jsibbold.zoomage.ZoomageView
                android:id="@+id/img_second_image"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginHorizontal="@dimen/margin_2"
                android:layout_marginVertical="@dimen/margin_2"
                android:contentDescription="@null"
                android:scaleType="matrix"
                android:src="@color/black"
                app:zoomage_animateOnReset="true"
                app:zoomage_autoCenter="true"
                app:zoomage_autoResetMode="UNDER"
                app:zoomage_maxScale="8"
                app:zoomage_minScale="0.6"
                app:zoomage_restrictBounds="false"
                app:zoomage_translatable="true"
                app:zoomage_zoomable="true" />
        </io.github.florent37.shapeofview.shapes.DiagonalView>

    </FrameLayout>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>


I tried using DiagonalView, a third party library but the angle doesn't seem right. The diagonal angle only runs from bottom right to middle of the image, while I want it to run from bottom right to bottom left (for both of the images). Are the any solutions for this problem?
